# How to control white spaces in the text

Tags: pdftex

I'm writing my PhD thesis in Latex. Unfortunately the white space between the words is not always the same so that it can appear that after the . no space is there (.my name is...) or sometimes a white space is there (. my name is...). Is there a way to control the presence of white spaces so that after the point (or other symbols) always a white space is there?

Thank you in advance

Best

Comment: Please do not only descibe your problem, please give us a MWE to play with. And in your case show us a screenshot and mark the parts were you think there is an error ...

Comment: You should always insert a space after an end-of-sentence period. Unless your editor allows for this, (La)TeX doesn't perform any auto-correction like a mobile device...

Comment: However, `frenchb` module for babel adds one, if I remember well. As for the O.P. question I think that generally speaking, it's rather an editor problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not practical to configure `LaTeX` to leaving automatically a *blank space* after of *punctuation* character. It's better to do it *manually* leaving at least a space.

If you refers to an extra space that `LaTeX` leaves after of the symbols `.` `:` `!` `?`, this can be **cancelled** with the *global declaration* `\frenchspacing` (and restored with `\nonfrenchspacing`). Some *languages* `\usepackage[<language>]{babel}` activate this order (as `spanish`).

With `\frenchspacing`, the space after of `.` `:` `!` `?` is the same as between words.

Compare

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
With \verb"\nonfrenchspacing" (by default).

\noindent Space after of a point. Or a colon: is wider! or not? It seems to be true.

\medskip
\frenchspacing
With \verb"\frenchspacing".

\noindent Space after of a point. Or a colon: is wider! or not? It seems to be true.
\end{document}!
```

[image]

Comment: Strange…  `frenchspacing` should also a thinspace (or  a medspace — not sure) `before` the colon.